# Can a non-linear transformation, specifically a translation, have eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, transformation

In trying to grasp the basics of linear algebra, I've encountered the following question:

> Let $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be the transformation
> defined by $(x,y) \mapsto (x+1,y+1)$. Does $f$ have any eigenvectors?
> Explain. What type of transformation is $f$?

I know that $f$ is a translation, which is a non-linear transformation. Does this mean that it has no eigenvectors? Do eigenvectors only apply to linear transformations?

Or can you actually have eigenvectors for non-linear transformations? If so, would **all** vectors be eigenvectors for this transformation? The transformation causes points to be translated 1 unit right and 1 unit up, but don't vectors stay the same? For example, the vector $\begin{bmatrix}3\\2\end{bmatrix}$ remains $\begin{bmatrix}3\\2\end{bmatrix}$. Before the transformation, it has initial point $(0,0)$ and terminal point $(3,2)$; after the transformation, it has initial point $(1,1)$ and terminal point $(4,3)$.

Hope you'll answer the quoted question, and also let me know if I've misunderstood anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, eigenvectors and eigenvalues are defined only for linear maps. And that map $f$ maps elements of $\Bbb R^2$ into elements of $\Bbb R^2$. In particular, it maps $(3,2)$ into $(4,3)$. Thinking about it as acting on vectors, by acting on their initial and final points, is misleading.

Comment: Thank you. Request for clarification: You're saying it's misleading to think of this map in terms of vectors, yet when it comes to learning linear algebra, so much of what I've learned is in terms of vectors. I can appreciate that thinking in vectors only makes sense when (0,0) maps to (0,0) — i.e. a linear map — so that vectors and points are essentially the same thing. Is that maybe the "point" of this problem? To underscore that thinking in vectors only works for linear maps?

Comment: I would no say that that's *the* point of the problem (after all, this has nothing to do with the fact that eigenvectors only make sense in the context of linear maps), but it is surely *a* point.

Answer (score 2):

The question has already been answered in the straightforward way, but I just wanted to point out another perspective. There is a way to view this as a linear map in some sense. It is an affine map, which can be represented as a matrix by embedding it in $\mathbb{R}^3$ as follows.
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0 \\ 1&1&0 \\ 1&0&1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ x+1 \\ y+1 \end{pmatrix} $$
Thinking about the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of this matrix may be another instructive perspective on the original problem.